# Find details of projects in BuildSettings.ProjectsToBuild in TFSBuild script

Tags: powershell, nuget, tfsbuild

I'm currently looking at creating a process to run during a TFS build that would create a NuGet package out of projects that match certain conditions. I would like to know if there's a way to get details of the projects in the `BuildSettings.ProjectsToBuild` stringList. I realise I could probably write a powershell function that could find the csproj file using just the name of the project and working out whether the project matches the conditions from there, but I'd like to do it in the build script.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version of TFS you're using, but check out this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9b0af022-c2c0-48f7-bcf0-89126630c3ba/use-projectstobuild-and-configurationstobuild-in-tfs-2013-powershell-scripts?forum=tfsbuild). Could be what you're looking for.

EDIT: You could then pass the value to a powershell script at build time.